# admob interstitial alway returns false

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am fairly new to AdMob. I tried looking up problem online and here but I can't find a solution that works for me.

So basically I am trying to create this game using Swift and in the `gameviewcontroller` I create 3 functions that create the ad and then I want to call them in my StartMenu scene.

Here is my functions for ad interstitial in `gameviewcontroller`:

```
func getInterstitialAd(){
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "AdMob Unit ID")
    let interstitialRequest = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(interstitialRequest)
}

func showAd() {
    print(interstitial.isReady)
    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        interstitial = createAd()
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
}

func createAd() -> GADInterstitial{
    let interstital = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "AdMob Unit ID")
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstital
}
```

and in my StartMenu Scene:

```
 var viewController = GameViewController()
```

I have this in my game over function and it basically gets called when the player dies:

```
viewController.getInterstitialAd()
viewController.showAd()
```

And every time the player dies it prints `false` and ad wasn't ready.

Comment: I think the problem is you call `showAd` function before the interstitial is created.

Comment: @DanhHuynh i added in my viewdidload in my gameviewcontroller to call the function getInterstitialAd() and still nothing happens, and also even if call showAd() first i thing the app would crash

Comment: Let create a button and call `showAd` when you press on it, just for testing purpose.

Comment: @DanhHuynh ok i did that but still nothing it prints " The interstitial Ad is loaded " then " False " then " Ad wasn't ready "

Comment: give me your Ad unit id, maybe it has some problem

Comment: i think the problem here is the way i call those functions from another scene , like i read that if i call it like that it creates another object so that's why it's empty but i don;t know how to probably call it

Comment: @DanhHuynh "ca-app-pub-1782852253088296/5018877964"

Comment: I think the problem is different viewController. Let try other approach

Comment: @DanhHuynh like what kind of approach ?

Comment: Maybe, create and show the Ad in the same viewController.

Comment: you mean like move all my functions to StartMenu scene instead on gameviewcontroller ?